# python, django, validate username with ajax

Tags: python, django, validation

I use ajax for authorization and I need to constantly check the username for validity. And also I have profile pages that look like `"my_site/username"` in the url. So I need to create a list of forbidden names like: `"sign_in", "home"` and so on.

So I wanted to ask if there are any ready-made functions (possibly from external packages) that perform full validation of the user name (including maximum length, forbidden characters).

Comment: Personally I always have the idea it is better to use something like `my_site/user/<username>`, that thus means that anything after the `user/` is allowed and this thus also means that there is simply no ambiguity possible.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This can be done, but I don't want the user to be able to create user names such as: "login", "admin", "logout", etc.  In addition, I will probably write my validation function with all the checks instead of using some packages. But I will be glad if there is a suitable one

Comment: but if you use unambiguous urls, a user named `logout` is *not* a problem, since that is `/user/logout`, whereas logging out would simply be `/logout` for example.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's right, I'll do it, Now my problem is half as small!